# My mouse does not work

Tags: usb, xorg, mouse

I have a Silvertec Optical Mouse Model:GM02.  It does not work after boot.  I tried to run this command after boot:

```
$ xsetpointer -l | grep Pointer
```

I get these results:

```
2: "Virtual core pointer"   [XPointer]
4: "Virtual core XTEST pointer" [XExtensionPointer]
13: "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"  [XExtensionPointer]
```

My current workaround are the following:

1. run these command on the terminal:

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get --purge autoremove xserver-xorg-input-all && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
   ```
2. remove my optical mouse from usb port.
3. restart ubuntu
4. wait until the the mouse pointer is visible
5. plug optical mouse to usb port

Any idea on what is wrong in my system?

Please help. :)